# Extract timestamp from timestamp string in redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm dealing with two redshift tables where each one have different formats of time stamps.

```
table 1 - start_date: 2013-07-26 07:30:17.0
table 2 - end_date: 20140517004819823Z
```

My requirement is to have both in the same format (like table 1, start date) so that i can use datediff to find the interval between them.

How do i format the table 2 end date similar to table 1. I've tried
cast(end_date as timestamp) but it throws  `Invalid data code: 8001`

Edit 1:

Tried Using `to_timestamp(end_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', false)` but it throws `Invalid operation: value for "YYYY" in source string is out of range;`

Comment: You can use: [TO_TIMESTAMP function - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_TIMESTAMP.html)

Comment: thanks John, but I'm stuck with `"YYYY" in source string is out of range"`. Any idea how to fix this

Comment: Please Edit your question to show the command that you are attempting to use, and the resulting error.

Comment: Your string is not formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS` -- it looks more like `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` and some other bits on the end. You will need to tell Redshift how the string is formatted so that it can convert it to a timestamp. Please read the linked documentation.

Comment: Correct, I tried `to_timestamp(end_date, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS', false)` and `20150425201043668Z` is getting returned as `2015-04-26 08:17:48.0`. Not sure if the timestamp is correct though.

Comment: You did not include the milliseconds, which seems to have impacted the seconds. See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use [TO_TIMESTAMP function - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_TIMESTAMP.html):

```
to_timestamp('20150425201043668Z', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSMSZ', true)
```

This translates:

- Date: `YYYYMMDD`
- Hour: `HH24`
- Minute: `MI`
- Seconds: `SS`
- Milliseconds: `MS`

Comment: Thanks, I did not want the millisecond part anyway, so I simply trimmed the last 4 characters as `to_timestamp(left(end_date,14),'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS', false) as end_date_utc`